# Jasper on RaspberryPi2 not starting

Tags: python

I tried using the jasper on RPI2 and followed the github for my installation and configuration. I am getting a following error which i could not solve. please help me out.

```
< *******************************************************
*             JASPER - THE TALKING COMPUTER           *
* (c) 2015 Shubhro Saha, Charlie Marsh & Jan Holthuis *
*******************************************************
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./jasper/jasper.py", line 148, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "./jasper/jasper.py", line 118, in run
    conversation.handleForever()
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/conversation.py", line 31, in handleForever
    threshold, transcribed = self.mic.passiveListen(self.persona)
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/mic.py", line 110, in passiveListen
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997
>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Arduino? Perhaps you meant to post this in [RaspberryPi.SE]?

Comment: Sorry brother i am quite new to stackExchange..!! Think i have posted on the wrong group.